# SharePoint 2013 Outgoing Email - Alerts

Tags: email, alert

I have outgoing email woorking fine.

When I add an alert to a list, the email goes on if an item is changed, however, the links are to the actual servername and not the hostname.

Links in the alert email are to

```
http://sever:100
```

instead of

```
http://mysite.contoso.com
```

Could this be related to alternate access mapping?

PS: I have two separate web applications running on the one SharePoint instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the Default AAM to `http://mysite.contoso.com`.

OR

Perhaps if you have changed Web Application URLs earlier, you might want to look into [Invoke-AlertFixup.ps1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508847(v=office.15).aspx) that can be used when Web app URL has changed. While this might fix the issue, make sure to also test it by creating new Alert after running the script.

Comment: Hi,  It was the AAM that fixed it, but only after an IISRESET /NOFORCE :-)